# Msg: Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Virtual Machine Platform is enabled and running
Virtualization is enabled in the bios.

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Craig
Registered Organization:   N/A
Product ID:                00330-52591-49274-AAOEM
Original Install Date:     5/9/2020, 5:24:12 PM
System Boot Time:          9/25/2020, 3:03:05 PM
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              XPS 15 7590'
```

```
PS C:\windows\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         1

PS C:\windows\system32> wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install
```

This was working once before.    I have tried uninstalling Virtual Machine Platform, WSL and Hyper-V multiple times.

If I try to run a Hyper-V machine I get
"Failed to start the virtual machine VM Name because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

The assumption is it thinks Virtual Machine Platform is not running.

I did download and install WSL update, I have run windows update.

Comment: The latest Windows 10 Production Version V2004 is 19041(.508).  It appears you may be running a Windows Insider version from a few months back. Try updating Windows Insider, restart and then try the above again.

Comment: WSL2 doesn’t actually require Hyper-V to be installed.

Comment: Have you downloaded the latest Linux kernel package?

Comment: I did run windows update.  WSL2 does not require Hyper-V, I do think the two problems are connected.  i.e if I fix one, I bet the other is fixed.  I did download and install the Linux Kernel package.     Thanks everyone

Comment: So is my first comment the answer for you?

Comment: John,  I have run update numerous times.   I am on the insider ring, but I keep the system current.   I have tried so many things, clearly something is causing it not to work.  I do believe I have done everything correctly.   I wish there were some way to debug or logs I could look at other than the Event Logs.